# How to accurately predict how much time environmental variables will add to a 5k

Tags: running

There are questions all over the internet saying, "How can I run a faster 5k?" and "Is a 25min 5k good?". As I read them, they are almost always assuming perfect conditions: dry pavement, minimal wind, completely flat ground, etc... Is there a good way to calculate how well I performed based on the circumstances? I know I could use Strava and compare it to the times of people around me, but they don't run my course.

I am asking: are there ways to accurately predict how much time environmental variables will add to my 5k times? Can I calculate how well I generally ran a 24min 40sec 3.4mi with 180ft climb and compare it to a lengthier route that may be equivalent? I feel like I am in moderate shape, but I still have a long ways to go...

I know running up hills uses various leg muscles that one might not use when running on completely flat ground.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I fear it's not very cut-and-dry though, because you can have some people who perform better than others on rough terrain, while others perform better on flat pavement. So it would be impossible to predict if you would run the same distance faster on different terrain without knowing what your particular specialties are.

Comment: @Alec I thought about that. I didn't know if there would be some other way. I have been running the same route a few times and the last time I ran it, I lowered my time by 3min. I was just wondering if there is a reason for that besides my body just recovering better this time?

Comment: I'm as hopeful for an answer as you are :)